# Device showing with 'adb devices' but not on visual studio (xamarin.android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android

**Device showing with 'adb devices' but not on visual studio (xamarin.android)**

[image]

[image]

I also tried connecting my device through `adb tcpip`

Answer (score 1):

In general, this problem can be examined from the following aspects:

1.Enable `Developer Options` on the device and revoke the `USB debugging` authorisation;

2.Install (e.g. to windows) the manufacturer's developer USB drivers for the device;

3.Ensure the `Minimum Android Version` in the AndroidManifest.xml is lower or equal to your device

4.Try to restart your Visual Studio and try again.